# Find the solution space over $\mathbb{R}$ when $|x|=\max\{-2x+1,(x/2)+1\}$

Tags: analysis

Find the solution space over $\mathbb{R}$ when 
$$
|x|=\max\{-2x+1,(x/2)+1\}
$$
 match the solution to one of the following below

The solution choices are:

(i) $\phi$

(ii) $\{2\}$

(iii) $\{-2,2\}$

(iv) $\{-2,2/3,2\}$

(v) $[0,2]$

(vi) $[2, \infty )$

I’m not sure how to start this or solve it any advice or hints would be helpful!

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Consider $x>0$, $x=0$, and $x<0$ separately.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can start to consider the maximum.

$$
-2x+1\leq (x/2)+1 \Leftrightarrow -2x\leq x/2 \Leftrightarrow x\geq \ldots
$$
Next, you consider the case $x\geq \ldots$ and $x<\ldots$ because for this cases you know what the maximum is.
Further, you have to get rid of $|x|$. The natural choise is to consider the cases $x\leq 0$ and $x>0$ to know the value of $x$.

You, you have two, three or four cases where you have a simple equation, you should be able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

When $x < 0$, the right side is $-2x+1$, but the solution of $|x| = -x = -2x+1$ is $x=1 > 0$, so in that case there are no solutions.

When $x = 0$, the right side is $1$, so there are no solutions unless $|x|=0=1$!

When $x>0$, the right side is $(x/2)+1$; solving $|x|=x=(x/2)+1$ gives $x/2=1$, i.e., $x=2$.  That (ii) is the only solution.

Comment: How do you get those numbers like in the first one |x|= -x =-2x+1 and how does that give 1>0?

Comment: If $x<0$ then $|x| = -x$.

Comment: Right I get that but how does that give 1>0

Comment: Also if $x<0$ then since $-2<1/2$, $-2x>x/2$ so $-2x+1>x/2$ and the max is $-2x+1$

Comment: The solution of $-x = -2x + 1$ is $x=1$, but we assumed $x<0$ and $1>0$, so there's no solution in this case.

Comment: I get it! Thank you!